# Suppose $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $ is the orthonormal system of functions in $L^2[0,1]$, if $e_n \in C^1[0,1]$, then $e_n'(x)$ can be unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $ is the orthonormal system of functions in $L^2[0,1]$, if $e_n \in C^1[0,1]$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\sup_n \max_{x\in [0,1]}|e_n'(x)|=\infty$.

I consider the opposite, if $\exists M>0,st\quad |e_n'(x)|\leq M,\forall n\in \mathbb{N} $, I wan't to prove there is a subsequence of $\{e_n\}$ which convergent uniformly to a continuous function, then we can get a contradicion, but I don't know how to prove $\{e_n\}$ is uniformy bounded, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $|e_n(x) | > M+2$, then by the mean value theorem $|e_n(y)| \geq 2$ for all $y \in [0,1]$, this contradicts $\Vert e_n \Vert_2 =1$.